# CSS Multiple backgrounds & IE 8 and earlier

Tags: css, internet-explorer, backwards-compatibility

I've applied the following CSS to an input button:

```
background: url(../images/bttn-border-left.png) left no-repeat,
            url(../images/bttn-border-right.png) right no-repeat, 
            url(../images/bttn-bg.png) center repeat-x;
```

My understanding is that IE8 and earlier won't support this. So my question is, what will happen? Will it show only the first background? Only the last? None of them? (I would check myself, but Windows 7 won't let me.)

Comment: Windows 7 has no say, why wouldn't it help you?

Comment: It says 7 and 8 aren't compatible.

Comment: if you are using IE9, simply use the developer tools(F12 on the keyboard) to set the Browser mode to other IE versions. Or you can download IE tester which help you test your page on IE4 to IE10

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Mathachew and Ibu.<br>
<br>
(And for anyone looking for the answer, IE 7 and 8 will ignore all the backgrounds listed in that rule; the solution is to do this:
    'background:url(../images/bttn-bg.png) repeat-x;
    background: url(../images/bttn-border-left.png) left no-repeat,
                url(../images/bttn-border-right.png) right no-repeat, 
                url(../images/bttn-bg.png) center repeat-x;'

Comment: Per CSS rules, if a CSS rule (or selector) is unknown, the entire thing will be skipped.  Using multiple URL in a background on IE8 and less will make the browser scratch it's head, shrug and move on, skipping the entire "background:" rule, and ignoring all images in that rule.  If you wanted to make some kind of default image, you could declare 2 background rules.  One with the default image and a second that overrides the "default" with multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Developer Tools in IE (press F12) and change the Browser Mode to IE8 and then IE7. You can also check out [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)